# Залипает спрайт при проверке выхода за границы поля. unity, 2d

Tags: c#, unity3d, 2d

Платформа застревает и при нажатии движения в обратною сторону нужно пдождать пока она начнёт двигаться.
Как убрать это залипание? Перестановка блоков кода не помогла.
[image: Картинка]

Вот код:

```
    void Update(){

    // горизонтальное движение
    playerPosition.x += Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") * playerVelocity * Time.deltaTime;

    // обновление позиции платформы
    transform.position = playerPosition;

    // проверка выхода за границы
    if (playerPosition.x < -boundary) {
        transform.position = new Vector3 (-boundary, playerPosition.y, playerPosition.z);
    } 
    if (playerPosition.x > boundary) {
        transform.position = new Vector3(boundary, playerPosition.y, playerPosition.z);     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может попробовать по другому?

Например, как мне кажется, проще поставить на границы (лево, право, верх) коллайдеры и платформе тоже добавить коллайдер (ну и `rigidbody2d` конечно) и всё. Платформа при столкновении с коллайдером дальше сама по себе уже не сможет двигаться, так что лишней работы не нужно будет делать. Т.е. будет всего лишь

```
void FixedUpdate () {
    float h = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");        
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.right * h * playerVelocity;
}
```

Еще вариант, такой:

Допустим, вы знаете ширину поля и просто хотите ограничить движение на +-8 единиц.
Тогда можно просто ограничить движение платформы с помощью [Mathf.Clamp](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html), которая не дает принимать значение меньше указанного минимального и больше указанного максимального, т.е.:

```
void Update() {
    float xPos = transform.position.x + (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * playerVelocity);
    playerPosition = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(xPos, -8f, 8f), -9.5f, 0f);
    transform.position = playerPosition;
}
```

Тут как раз говорим - двигайся по координате икс, но не меньше -8 и не больше +8;

---

А вообще `playerPosition.x` вроде как находится в центре объекта, если мне не изменяет память, поэтому нужно как минимум проверять

```
playerPosition.x - player.width/2 <= леваяГраница
```

и

```
playerPosition.x + player.width/2 >= праваяГраница`
```

так что возможно причина в этом.

Answer (score 0):

Исправил тем, что добавил платформе Rigidbody2D, поставил по бокам стенки и прописал другое движение.

```
void FixedUpdate(){

    float move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(move * maxSpeed, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);

}
```